# What is returned when I call ToString() on an uninitialized char object property?

Tags: c#

I have a c# object with a property called Gender which is declared as a char.

```
private char _Gender;
public char Gender
{
    get{ return _Gender; }
    set{ _Gender = value; }

}
```

What string is returned/created when I call MyObject.Gender.ToString()?

I ask because I am calling a webservice (which accepts a string rather than a char) so I am doing a ToString on the property as I pass it over. I was expecting it to send an empty string if the char is not set.

However this doesn't appear to be the case, so the question is what is the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value of char is unicode 0, so I'd expect "\u0000" to be returned.

Answer (score 2):

Fields are always initialized to their default value; 0/false/null - this this is the 0 character, \0.

If you want an empty string, use strings directly - i.e. "".

You could use a conditional operator:

```
string s = c == 0 ? "" : c.ToString();
```

Alternatively, nullable types might help - i.e.

```
char? c; // a field
...
string s = c.ToString(); // is ""
c = 'a';
s = c.ToString(); // is "a"
```

Comment: Yes, but since string literals are interned, there is very little to choose between them; "" doesn't create a new instance each time. I find "" much clearer (less verbose), and I value clarity hugely.

Comment: Et voila; no difference *at all* (returns true): string s = "", t = string.Empty;
        Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(s,t));

Answer (score 0):

A char has a length of 1, so it never should return an empty string.

If you want to distinguish between 0 and uninitialised, you would need to use the nullable form char?.